# How to slow down the timer using tkinter

Tags: python, timer, tkinter

I'm trying to make the timer slow down in a function or even stop the timer when a function is called.
Tried doing .remove .forget but nothing would work.
Any ways to stop/slow down the timer?

```
from tkinter import *
import time

class App():
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = Tk()
        self.root = Frame(self.window, height=200,width=200)
        self.root.pack()
        self.root.pack_propagate(0)
        self.window.title('Timer')
        self.label = Label(text="")
        self.label.pack()
        self.sec = 11
        self.timerupdate()
        self.root.mainloop()
    def timerupdate(self):
        if self.sec!=0:
            self.sec-=1
            self.label.configure(text=self.sec)
            self.root.after(1000, self.timerupdate)

        if self.sec == 0:
          self.sec = 11

        self.slow_time()

    def slow_time(self):
        self.after.configure(1000000000,self.counting)

app=App()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: "Slow down"? What does that mean?

Comment: What is `self.after` in the code? No definition here.

Answer (score 0):

The only timer in the code is when you call `self.root.after(1000, self.timerupdate)`. The `1000` is what controls the speed. It designates how far in the future to call a function, and is represented as a number of milliseconds. If you want to run something every second, use the value `1000`. If you want to run something every two seconds, the value is `2000`, and every half second would be `500`.

So, store the speed in a variable, use that variable when you call `self.after`, and then you simply change that variable whenever you want to speed up or slow down the timer.